# How to construct generic type from symbol info in roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have `INamedTypeSymbol`, lets say `MyAwsomeApp.Foo`. I would like to wrap it in `Action<>`. How I can achieve this?

Expected output is INamedTypeSymbol - `System.Action<MyAwseomeApp.Foo>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [INamedType.Construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.inamedtypesymbol.construct?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.1.0) method for that, e.g.

```
var actionOfT = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeof(Action<>).FullName);
var foo = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyAwseomeApp.Foo");
var actionOfFoo = actionOfT.Construct(foo);
```

Comment: Hey there, just a quick reminder to edit your profile in SE. Cheers, and good luck with new adventures! :)